# Python - Applying condition on after decimal point (in dataframe column)

Tags: python, django, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains a column like below,

```
total_hours

8.31,
5.15,
10.53,
8.69,
10.57,
10.53
14.25,
10.55,
0.0,
10.73,
8.54,
10.55,
0.0,
10.53,
10.52,
10.54
```

I have to apply condition after decimal point, Those conditions are,
( (<50)it will replace .0), and (>50) it will replace .5)). How can i do it properly???
Thanks in advance,....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement your own rounding criteria in a function, and apply the function on required column:

```py
def customRound(val):
    fraction = val-int(val)
    return int(val)+0.5 if fraction>=0.5 else int(val)

df['total_hours']=df['total_hours'].apply(customRound)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
    total_hours
0           8.0
1           5.0
2          10.5
3           8.5
4          10.5
5          10.5
6          14.0
7          10.5
8           0.0
9          10.5
10          8.5
11         10.5
12          0.0
13         10.5
14         10.5
15         10.5
```

Comment: Thank tou so much for reply,..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
total_hours = [8.31, 5.15, 10.53, 8.69, 10.57, 10.53, 14.25, 10.55, 0.0, 10.73, 8.54, 10.55, 0.0, 10.53, 10.52, 10.54]
new_hours = []
for number in total_hours:
    cal = number - int(number)
    if cal < 0.5:
        sum = 0
    else:
        sum = 0.5

    out = float(int(number) + sum)
    new_hours.append(out)
print(new_hours)

>>[8.0, 5.0, 10.5, 8.5, 10.5, 10.5, 14.0, 10.5, 0.0, 10.5, 8.5, 10.5, 0.0, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5]
```